# What is the name of matrices of this form?

Tags: matrices

Consider the upper traingular $N \times N$ matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & b_{1} & \dots & b_{q} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & 0 & b_{1} & \dots & b_{q} & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  &  &  & \vdots\\
\vdots &  &  & 0 & b_{1} & \dots & b_{q} & 0\\
\vdots &  &  &  & 0 & b_{1} & \dots & b_{q}\\
\vdots &  &  &  &  & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots &  &  &  &  &  & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Is there a name for matrices of this form?

Comment: "Weird upper triangular matrices..."?

Answer (score 2):

The upper block has several properties that you can combine in a name:

> strictly [upper triangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix), [Toeplitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), [band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) matrix with a right/upper bandwidth $q$.

However, if you want to describe the whole matrix, you lose the "Toeplitz" part. You might say

> These matrices are of form
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} X \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> where $0$ is a zero matrix of order $q \times n$, and $X$ is strictly [upper triangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix), [Toeplitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), [band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) matrix of order $(n-q) \times q$ with a right/upper bandwidth $q$.

However, I believe a formal, nameless description is far better.

Answer (score 0):

There is, so far as I know, no standard name for this type of matrix. However, it is composed of the first $q$ superdiagonals of the matrix, so "q-superdiagonal matrix" might be a sensible thing to call them.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly (zeros on the diagonal) upper triangular (obvious) banded (has a limited band) Toeplitz (is a diagonal-constant) matrix.

You can call it a StrUTriBaToM :-)

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but observe the zeroes in the bottom right block. That's why I had to amend my answer.

Comment: Ah indeed, well then StrUTriBaToM could become StrUTriBATOM for strictly upper triangular banded almost Toeplitz matrix.